# sqlalchemy hybrid_attribute expression

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Assuming the following models:

```
class Worker(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'workers'
    ...
    jobs = relationship('Job',
                        back_populates='worker',
                        order_by='desc(Job.started)',
                        lazy='dynamic')

    @hybrid_property
    def latest_job(self):
        return self.jobs.first()  # jobs already ordered descending

    @latest_job.expression
    def latest_job(cls):
        Job = db.Model._decl_class_registry.get('Job')
        return select([func.max(Job.started)]).where(cls.id == Job.worker_id).as_scalar()

class Job(Model):
    ...
    started = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    worker_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('workers.id'))
    worker = db.relationship('Worker', back_populates='jobs')
```

While this query provides correct results:

```
db.session.query(Worker).join(Job.started).filter(Job.started >= datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 10, 0, 2, 45, 932983)).distinct().count()
```

I was under the assumption I could query that field directly, but this query fails:

```
db.session.query(Worker).join(Job).filter(Worker.latest_job.started >= datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 10, 0, 2, 45, 932983)).count()
```

with this error:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'hybrid_property' object nor 'ExprComparator' object associated with Worker.latest_job has an attribute 'started'
```

How can I query this property directly? What am I missing here?

EDIT 1:
Following @Ilja advice from his answer, I have attempted:

```
db.session.query(Worker).\
    join(Job).\
    filter(Worker.latest_job >= datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 10, 0, 2, 45, 932983)).\
    count()
```

but get this error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Select' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: If you're getting `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'Select' and 'datetime.datetime'`, you've removed the call to `as_scalar()`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä after digging around I see what you were trying to show me. Coming from Django I was expecting certain behavior which doesn't map to SQL the way SA does. Your answer was helpful and I would like to select it but it has been deleted. Please repost it.

Comment: @IljaEverilä are scalar values the only kind allowed to be returned in subqueries?

Comment: No, you can for example compare a constructed row against a subquery's result, or results if using the `IN` predicate. Also it is quite common to use subqueries in the `FROM` clause to produce derived tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a scalar subquery from your hybrid property when used in SQL (class) context, so just use it as you'd use a value expression:

```
db.session.query(Worker).\
    filter(Worker.latest_job >= datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 10, 0, 2, 45, 932983)).\
    count()
```

The hybrid property itself needs to explicitly handle correlation in this case:

```
@latest_job.expression
def latest_job(cls):
    Job = db.Model._decl_class_registry.get('Job')
    return select([func.max(Job.started)]).\
        where(cls.id == Job.worker_id).\
        correlate(cls).\
        as_scalar()
```

Note that there's some asymmetry between your hybrid property's Python side and SQL side. It produces the latest `Job` object when accessed on an instance, compared to producing a correlated scalar subquery of `max(started)` in SQL. If you'd like it to return a `Job` row in SQL as well, you'd do something like

```
@latest_job.expression
def latest_job(cls):
    Job = db.Model._decl_class_registry.get('Job')
    return Job.query.\
        filter(cls.id == Job.worker_id).\
        order_by(Job.started.desc()).\
        limit(1).\
        correlate(cls).\
        subquery()
```

but that's actually less useful mostly, because usually – but not always – this kind of correlated subquery will be slower than joining against a subquery. For example in order to fetch workers with latest jobs that meet the original criteria:

```
job_alias = db.aliased(Job)
# This reads as: find worker_id and started of jobs that have no matching
# jobs with the same worker_id and greater started, or in other words the
# worker_id, started of the latest jobs.
latest_jobs = db.session.query(Job.worker_id, Job.started).\
    outerjoin(job_alias, and_(Job.worker_id == job_alias.worker_id,
                              Job.started < job_alias.started)).\
    filter(job_alias.id == None).\
    subquery()

db.session.query(Worker).\
    join(latest_jobs, Worker.id == latest_jobs.c.worker_id).\
    filter(latest_jobs.c.started >= datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 10, 0, 2, 45, 932983)).\
    count()
```

and of course if you just want the count, then you don't need the join at all:

```
job_alias = db.aliased(Job)
db.session.query(func.count()).\
    outerjoin(job_alias, and_(Job.worker_id == job_alias.worker_id,
                              Job.started < job_alias.started)).\
    filter(job_alias.id == None,
           Job.started >= datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 10, 0, 2, 45, 932983)).\
    scalar()
```

Please note that the call to [`Query.scalar()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.scalar) is not the same as [`Query.as_scalar()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.as_scalar),  but just returns the first value of the first row.

Comment: This throws an error: `InvalidRequestError: Select statement 'SELECT max(jobs.started) AS max_1 FROM jobs, workers 
WHERE workers.id = jobs.worker_id' returned no FROM clauses due to auto-correlation; specify correlate(<tables>) to control correlation manually.`

Comment: also, wouldn't I have to do `filter(Worker.latest_job.started >= datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 10, 0, 2, 45, 932983))` or else how will the db know how to compare them by the `started` field?

Comment: You would not have to. The definition of a scalar subquery, usable as a scalar value, is that it is a table of 1 row, of 1 column. SQL is funny that way, and I'd wish it wasn't that "magical". Regarding the correlation issue, just add `correlate(cls)` to your `select()` construct, before `as_scalar()`.

Comment: For example this is true: `select 1 = (select 1);`. In SQL (almost) everything is a table. In fact the comparison `=` is defined in terms of rows, and when you say `1 = 1` it actually means `(1) = (1)`, or in other words compare this row of 1 column to this other row of 1 column.

Comment: A <comparison predicate> is defined in the standard as `<comparison predicate> ::= <row value predicand> <comparison predicate part 2>`, where `<comparison predicate part 2> ::= <comp op> <row value predicand>`.

Comment: perhaps I misunderstood the `as_scalar` method, I should read up on what exactly that does in this query. Considering what I am attempting (querying attributes of the `Job` model  through the `latest_job` hybrid property on the `Worker` model) is the use of that method necessary? And either way how would you recommend I approach this? Also, any links to definitions and proper use of `as_scalar` and scalar subqueries would be appreciated.

Comment: after re-reading your first comment, how does SA know which column to use to represent the `Job` model as a scalar value in that query?

Comment: assuming I wanted just `latest_job_started` date, how would that aliased query look? Also, when used the "correlated scalar subquery of max(started)", why when I do `session.query(Worker.latest_job_started).all()` does it only produce a single value as opposed to a column? I was under the impression that these expressions were supposed to return columns.

Comment: Technically `session.query(Worker.latest_job_started).all()` produces a list of result tuples. The reason it is not a 1-tuple of column of ... is that SQL treats a scalar subquery specially, as if a value.

Comment: your second example of latest_job.expression returning a Job row (using select and `.subquery()` chained method) raises an exception: `AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'subquery'`. What is the proper way to return a row which I can then query the attributes of like a foreignkey relation?

Comment: Usually you'd use a suitable join. Fixed the mish mash of ORM and Core style that you noted.