# SQLAlchemy: hybrid property, sort and return first

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have the following models. A pizza's status can be updated multiple times, but I want my Pizza model to have a `latest_status` which returns the most recent status:

```
class PizzaStatus(Base):
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    type = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    pizza_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("pizzas.id"))


class Pizza(Base):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Always load the statuses when querying an object
    statuses = relationship("PizzaStatus", backref="pizza", lazy="selectin")

    @typed_hybrid_property
    def latest_status(self):
        return max(self.statuses, key= lambda status: status.updated_at)

    @latest_status.expression
    def latest_status(cls):
        return select([Pizza.statuses]).where(PizzaStatus.pizza_id == cls.id).order_by(desc(PizzaStatus.updated_at)).first()
```

I can, when I have fetched a `Pizza` object, do this:

```
pizza = session.query(Pizza).all()
pizza.latest_status
```

Which means the hybrid property implemented on the instance level of `Pizza` works.

However, I can't do this:

```
session.query(Pizza).filter(Pizza.latest_status.type.in_(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'first'
```

Here is what I would like to achieve: when querying `Pizza` objects from my database, I want to filter pizzas based on their latest status. I want these statuses to be in a list of valid status types. I have tried approaches like this one: [sqlalchemy hybrid_attribute expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55622232/sqlalchemy-hybrid-attribute-expression), but I couldn't get them to work. Could you give me a hand please?

Answer (score 0):

Try `limit(1)` instead of `first`. One is for the ORM, the other for core (which you are using)